# Storing Amazon S3 keys in private repo

Tags: security, github, amazon-s3

Is it safe for me to store my Amazon S3 keys/secrets in a private Github repo?  I know that it is not safe for a public repo but I am wondering if a private repo is safe?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [GitHub Security page](https://help.github.com/articles/github-security/):

> We do not encrypt repositories on disk because it would not be any more secure: the website and git back-end would need to decrypt the repositories on demand, slowing down response times

So if there is any leak ([like in 2012](https://it.slashdot.org/story/12/03/05/1243235/github-hacked?SetFreedomCookie)), your data is out as well.
You can see that [approach being criticized in this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11662364).

I would recommend an external service that you control for your secrets.
For instance, [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

@vonc is correct but if dont want to setup and maintain vault, you can consider using aws parameter store (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/parameter-store/) to store your secrets keys which is lot easier.

Comment: I found this solution after so long as I wanted to maintain sync with my teammates on env contents.